# Delphi: stop idHTTP working while time out is

Tags: delphi, timeout, disconnect, idhttp

I do `idHTTP.Get('http://example.com/1.zip', FStream);`

A server doesn't response...and idHTTP waits for a connect to download a file

I need to stop idHTTP working. If it's connected I can do `idHTTP1.Disconnect`.

But what about a time when idHTTP isn't connected, when a time out is, and idHTTP waits for a connect -> we are waiting, waiting and then a time out exception will raise (**I need to stop working in this waiting time**). So I cannot do `idHTTP1.Disconnect`. If to do that then  a `not connected` exception will raise, because of we are not connected.

How to stop working while waiting for a connect without an exception?

Thanks!

Comment: Maxfax: Do you visist `http://xxx.com` regularly? :) Please use `http://example.com` as your sample domain name next time!

Answer (score 1):

The maximum time for the connect operation of a TidHTTP component can be limited with the `ConnectTimeout` property.